# EJB TimerService: Changing location of file data store

Tags: java, timer, jboss, ejb

I'm using EJB's TimerService, and persisting timers using the file data store. Files are located in `standalone/data/timer-service-data/applicationname-fullversion-buildnumber.NameOfBean`.

**Every time I bump the version or build number, timers will be located in a new directory and I lose persistence.**

Looking through the configuration XML, it appears that I can change the base directory for timer persistence, but I can't seem to find anywhere to specify what to use to identify the application. Preferably I would like to use the application name and probably a major version, stripping out minor version and build number, making sure the application uses the same timer data store across minor versions.

I'm using JBoss 6.4.5.GA.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can configure the path of the timer service related files.

See the official documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_the_EJB3_timer_Service.html)

> Login
>       Login to the Management Console.
>
> ```
> Open the Timer Service Tab
> Click on Profile in the top right, expand the Container item in the Profile panel on the left and select EJB 3. Select the Services
> ```
>
> tab from the main panel and then the Timer Service tab.
>
> ```
> Enter Edit Mode
> Click the Edit Button. The fields become editable.
>
> Make the Required Changes.
> You can select a different EJB3 thread pool used for the Timer Service if additional thread pools have been configured, and you can
> ```
>
> change the directory used to save the Timer Service data. The Timer
>   Service data directory configuration consists of two values: Path, the
>   directory that data is stored in; and Relative To, the directory which
>   contains Path. By default Relative To is set to a Filesystem Path
>   Variable.

Comment: It looks very much like the general Path-setting under Configuration > Container > EJB 3 > Services is the *base* directory for timers, not the specific directory name for each timer. It looks like it's using the application name for that, and I was looking to change that programmatically or in the application configuration.